# The way of using loop in this simple syntax

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I want to use select, and write.csv function, but for 9 iterations. Currently my original data(aggregated_rate) contains many variables and I'd divide it and save into 9 files. So followings are what I coded, but I want to deal with this with loop function(whatever it is).

```
rate_1 = aggregated_rate %>% select(ID, length, rate1)
write.csv(rate_1,"C:/Users/Documents/rate_1")

rate_2 = aggregated_rate %>% select(ID, length, rate2)
write.csv(rate_2,"C:/Users/Documents/rate_2")

...

rate_9 = aggregated_rate %>% select(ID, length, rate9)
write.csv(rate_9,"C:/Users/Documents/rate_9")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide your data(`aggregated_rate`), I'll explain with dummy data `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1,
  length = 2,
  rate1 = 1,
  rate2 = 2,
  rate3 = 3
)

  ID length rate1 rate2 rate3
1  1      2     1     2     3
```

You may use loops like

```
for(i in 1:3){
  x <- paste0("rate", i)
  print(df[,c("ID","length",x)])
}

  ID length rate1
1  1      2     1
  ID length rate2
1  1      2     2
  ID length rate3
1  1      2     3
```

For your purpose, code below may works.

```
for (i in 1:9){
  x <- paste0("rate", i)
  y <- aggregated_rate[,c("ID","length",x)]
  path <- paste0("C:/Users/Documents/rate_", i, ".csv", row.names=FALSE)
  write.csv(y, path)
}
```

Be aware your path `C:/Users/Documents/` do exist.